# Does Heroic(TSDBMS) identifies series with its Resource Identifiers?

Tags: database, time-series, spotify, spotify-app

From the doc about [Data Model](https://spotify.github.io/heroic/docs/data_model):

> A series is identified by key, and a unique set of tags and resource
> identifiers.

But there are no api about `resource identifiers`, put/get/post, no api related.

So, is `resource identifiers` really part of series identifier in Heroic?